# INFORMATICA - Java Transformation - Dynamic Arrays

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I've an input row that is a name of names separated by spaces (like Informatica Academy, The Lousy Informatica Ctr, Power Center Tech, etc). A Java Transformation can help store the names in array but can the output rows vary by the array length (in the example above, 2, 4 and 3). Later, I'll be validating each name against a lookup table if it is the abbreviated version like Ctr for Center, Tech for Technology; and then pass the expanded name as the output.

Comment: Sorry, we have no idea what you're talking about.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: @JimGarrison the question is regarding PowerCenter which is a data integration product from Informaitca. It happens to support embedding java code.

Comment: Could you confirm my understanding of your question is correct, you want to send one port into the java transformation and for the java transformation to spit out one output port which contains the word count of the port which had been sent in? I don't understand why it has to be a java transformation given you could work this out inline within an expression transformation just generating an output port with an expression to calculate the number of spaces + 1. Examples like port length - port length without spaces are shown here https://network.informatica.com/thread/42439

Comment: If you ask wether the output rows can contain a dynamic number of columns, the answer is NO, but as written below, the number of rows can vary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can generate any number of rows from an input row in Java transformation. Loop over the array elements and for each iteration assign the output ports followed by a call to `generateRow()` function.

Comment: If you're looking for sample code, there is some posted along the same lines by S K here network.informatica.com/thread/9843